# Matplotlib / Seaborn legend changes style upon adding labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting some of my data from a pandas df using seaborn. Almost everything plots nicely using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted')

legend = ["Hue 1", "Hue 2"]
order = ["A", "B"]

ax = sns.violinplot(x=df.xaxis, y=df.yaxis, hue=df.hue,
                    split=True, order=order)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set(xlabel='X - axis', ylabel='Y - axis')
ax.legend(title='Legend', loc='upper left', labels=legend)
ax.set_title('My little plot')
plt.show()
```

As soon as I add the `labels=` there is a change in 'linetype' shown in the legend. Below is a screenshot. Unfortunately my dataset is too large to publish so I hope this is enough.

Thanks in advance. BBQuercus :)

Left without, right with `labels` (R, C are the values in my data).

[image: Without labels]
[image: With labels]

Comment: Maybe you could pass the handles for the patches that are being drawn in the violin plot to the ```ax.legend``` function. You could find the handles under ```ax.collections```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to draw custom patches for your legend. I haven't tested this but I think that it should work.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
palette=sns.color_palette('muted')

bluepatch = Patch(
    facecolor=palette[0],edgecolor='k',label='Hue 1'
)
orangepatch = Patch(
    facecolor=palette[1],edgecolor='k',label='Hue 2'
)

ax.legend(
    labels=['Hue 1','Hue 2'], 
    handles=[bluepatch, orangepatch], 
    title='Legend', 
    loc='upper left'
)
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks so much!